# Trouble with basic Salesforce API/PHP Script

Tags: php, api, soap, salesforce

I am trying to increase the little knowledge I have of PHP by building a simple application that utilizes data obtained via the Salesforce API. Here's what I've got so far, mostly through copy/paste and by looking at example code:

```
<?php

define("USERNAME", "");
define("PASSWORD", "");
define("SECURITY_TOKEN", "");

require_once ('[file-path]/SforceEnterpriseClient.php');

$mySforceConnection = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
$mySforceConnection->createConnection("[file-path]/wsdl.jsp.xml");
$mySforceConnection->login(USERNAME, PASSWORD.SECURITY_TOKEN);

$query = "SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Phone from Contact";
$response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);

echo "Results of query '$query'<br/><br/>\n";
foreach ($response->records as $record) {
    // Id is on the $record, but other fields are accessed via the fields object
    echo $record->Id . ": " . $record->fields->FirstName . " "
        . $record->fields->LastName . " " . $record->fields->Phone . "<br/>\n";
}

?>
```

Problem is, when I try to run this script (http://moneythink.org/sf-app.php), the server just returns an error message; no idea why this is happening.

Any and all assistance would be very greatly appreciated!

Comment: what's the error message ?

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to get this script to work. Here's the functioning code:

```
<?php

define("USERNAME", "");
define("PASSWORD", "");
define("SECURITY_TOKEN", "");

require_once ('SforceEnterpriseClient.php');

$mySforceConnection = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
$mySforceConnection->createConnection("[path-file]/enterprise.wsdl.xml");
$mySforceConnection->login(USERNAME, PASSWORD.SECURITY_TOKEN);

$query = "SELECT Id, Name  FirstName, LastName, University__c from Contact";
$response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);

foreach ($response->records as $record) {
    echo 'ID:' .' '. $record->Id . '<br>';
    echo 'First Name:' .' '. $record->FirstName . "<br>";
    echo 'Last Name:' .' '. $record->LastName . "<br>";
    echo 'University:' .' '. $record->University__c . "<br>";
    echo "<br>\n";
}

echo "Size of records:  ".$response ->size;

?>
```

As part of this new code, I created a new Enterprise WSDL from Salesforce, and also removed the file path from the SforceEnterpriseClient.php (my script is in the same directory).

Comment: What file did you put all this code in? I am having trouble doing the same.